# Problemas com iframe e jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

Bom tenho um pequeno e grande problema com iframe.

```
<iframe src="index.php"  frameborder="0" name="site" class="site"></iframe>
<iframe src="toca/player.php?volume=100" name="player"  frameborder="0" class="toca"></iframe>
```

Simples quero que quando o usuario clicar em pausar o volume do iframe player mudar para 0 ou se o usuario escolher um certo volume tipo 50, 40, 10...

No caso é pra um controlador de volume que ja está codificado sendo assim só falta fazer com que ele deminua o volume

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu quero que seja com jquery pelo fato do controle ser feito em jquery portanto o valor é gerado em jquery e o valor é o volume do frame player que contem essa codificação
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tiver um forma melhor de fazer isso pode falar s2

Comment: Para responder essa pergunta, precisamos de mais informações... Cade o botão? O botão é um elemento html? Aonde é esse player que vc mencionou?

Comment: mals fiz um resumo ai grato